Default values in python dataclass
I have a quick (silly) question about how a python dataclass handles default values. If I run the following example:
@dataclass
class Test:
    name: str
    id: int = random.randint(0, 1000)

for i in range(1, 10):
    t = Test(
        f"Test {i}"
    )
    print(t.id, t.name)

I get the same id for every Test instance t. Presumably the id attribute is just constant and randint is only called once. So I was wondering how exactly the constructor works and if there is a way to call randintfor each new instance.
Thank you very much in advance!

You can use field to add custom logic to a field's initialization:
@dataclass
class Test:
    name: str
    id: int = field(default_factory = lambda: random.randint(0, 1000))

The function passed to the field will be executed each time a Test object is crated. E.g., when running the same for loop as the OP, I got the following output:
10 Test 1
334 Test 2
430 Test 3
224 Test 4
316 Test 5
1 Test 6
368 Test 7
173 Test 8
248 Test 9


Another way is to use __post_init__() which runs for every instance after the automatic init for the dataclass. This is useful for all sorts of instance initialization.
@dataclass
class Test:
    name: str
    id: int = None
    def __post_init__(self):
        self.id = random.randint(0,1000)


for i in range(1, 4):
    t = Test(
        f"Test {i}")
    print(t.id, t.name)

gives:
49 Test 1
630 Test 2
444 Test 3


If you want an id attribute that doesn't change, there's this field function that assigns id after instantiation of the class in the __post_init__ method.
Otherwise, you can simply use a lambda function.
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from random import randint


@dataclass
class Test:
    name: str
    id: int = field(init=False)

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.id = random.randint(0, 1000)

for i in range(1, 10):
    t = Test(f"Test {i}")
    print(t.id, t.id, t.name)

Output:
317 Test 1
320 Test 2
617 Test 3
14 Test 4
369 Test 5
664 Test 6
175 Test 7
764 Test 8
83 Test 9

